# Javascript Fetch does not work with URLsearchparams on Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

Can someone explain to me why this code doesn't produce an http request on Edge?
https://jsfiddle.net/sectioni/tyr5fLgc/1/

```
let url = "/test.aspx";

// don't change this to a const because the append will not work in Edge
let data = new URLSearchParams();
data.append("userPreferences", "bla");

let promise = fetch(url, {
  method: "POST", // POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
  body: data,
  cache: "no-cache", // no-store, reload, no-cache, force-cache, or only-if-cached
  keepalive: true
});
```

It does work on Chrome & Firefox, and if you remove the body part, the request is sent on Edge.

Comment: Which version of Edge you are trying on? https://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams

Comment: @tanaydin  42.17134.1098.0
According to caniuse it should work then...

Comment: With Edge 44 the request is sent, but I can't see the parameter in the request's headers with the developer toolbar

Comment: maybe try a polyfill? https://github.com/jerrybendy/url-search-params-polyfill

Comment: Since Edge supports URLSearchParams, I don't think a polyfill would do anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that since Edge have switched to using Chromium, it's now possible to download Edge directly in order to update it.

Once testing with Edge 81, the problem no longer occurs. Which would make it a bug with older Edge versions.